# IOS selector from addObserver:selector:name:object does not execute in view controller

Tags: ios, nsnotifications, addobserver

Context
We were developing an ios app that can uses opencv and had to change our `viewcontrollers` to .mm

opencv related functions in the .mm won't execute code that involves changes in the ui.
`GazeTracker` is an `NSObject` that tells the state of the user's gaze and it works fine

we thought of using observers so that we'll use a selector in the `viewController` called stateChanged which will execute whenever the state in `gazeTracker` is changed.

"`stateChanged`" is never called. We initially thought it was just `gazeTracker` so we replaced it with "`self`" (meaning the `viewController`) and it still won't work.
Our understanding of the "`observer`" is that when a value in an object is changed, the `selector` is called. However we don't know the purpose of "`object`" in "`addObserver:selector:name:object`".

```
the original code

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:gazeTracker.state
selector:@selector(stateChanged) 
name:@"stateChanged" 
object:nil];

}
-(void)stateChanged{
NSLog(@"some value in gaze tracker has changed");
}

with "self"

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(stateChanged) 
name:@"stateChanged" 
object:nil];

}
-(void)stateChanged{
NSLog(@"some value in gaze tracker has changed");
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting confused between notification and KVO. In your code you are registering for a notification with name `stateChanged`. This notification must be posted by some entity in your code on required state change. In KVO you can register for changes in particular properties of an instance.

Comment: @Amar Uhm, thanks but we don't understand what you just said. We are very new to xcode. We just want a method to be called when a change occurs in the value of an object. The work around we did just now is to use a thread in the viewcontroller that checks if there is any change, then calls a method in the viewcontroller that will do something when the change happens. but we think there is a better way to do this. we tried to read the documentation in the ios dev site but we didn't understand it either.